# how to close ports with no process attachedto it

Tags: ubuntu, ps, netstat

how do you close ports if there are not processes attached to it? I used to run an application and they're using this ports previously for some reason the application crashed but if i restart the application, i frequently need to change the port because the port is being used. But if I try to issue this command.

```
netstat -lnp

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
    
    tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
    tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

PID/Program Name is not attached to a process its just "-". So anyone know hows to close off this port?

## SOLVED

Just discovered that some process are being run by root and it would not show if you don't do sudo keyword before the command.

```
sudo netstat -tulpn

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp6       0      0 :::8090                 :::*                    LISTEN      1242/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1491/java
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `netstat -tulpn` it clearly shows

`Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info will not be shown,you would have to be root to see it all.`